# Including a field in the View that is not part of the data model

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

What's the best way to include a date field on the View that does not have a corresponding column in the DB? For example:

```
Model:
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[Display(Name = "Review Date")]
[Required]
public DateTime? ReviewDate { get; set; }


View:
@model Model.Employee
...
<div>
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.ReviewDate)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ReviewDate)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ReviewDate})
</div>
```

But I don't have a column ReviewDate in the DB table. I just need to have this in the view to collect the date entry from the user for other processing, but it's not part of my data model. I thought of including this in the model class only so that I can control the attributes for validation, etc.

What is the best approach for this? Should I remove this from the model and just have an isolated HTML date field in the view? If so, how can I ensure the validation still works on that field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply create a ViewModel which contains the properties needed for that specific view.

```
public class EmployeeEditViewModel
{
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [Display(Name = "Review Date")]
    [Required]
    public DateTime? ReviewDate { get; set; }

    public EmployeeModel Employee { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your Razor you can do something along these lines:

```
@model ViewModel.EmployeeEditViewModel
...
<div>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ReviewDate)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ReviewDate)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ReviewDate)
</div>
<div>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Employee.SomeValue)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Employee.SomeValue)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Employee.SomeValue)
</div>
```